# How to test HorizontalAccuracy

Tags: swift2

I am using HorizontalAccuracy to determine if the GPS signal is good, weak or none but I am developing from a spot that has great GPS coverage so I was wondering how (if at all) I can test HorizontalAccuracy in my app?

Is there a way to simulate a bad coverage area?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to simulate location updates via a GPX file as in Xcode->Debug->Simulate Location, but I've never tried that. In the mean time, try requesting a lower accuracy result from CoreLocation to test how your app responds.

On a related note, this is a great use case for unit testing. You can pass your delegate functions pre-made updates and ensure it handles them correctly.